# Docker containers have no internet, I've tried many solutions

Tags: ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean, iptables, internet-connection

I have docker containers running on Ubuntu 16.04 on Digital Ocean. They worked well but one day (I think it happened after **TOR1 Droplet Reboot 2018-02-28 16:00 UTC [Spectre and Meltdown Mitigation]** but I'm not sure) they have lost their internet connection and I do not know why and how to make it work.
I have tried many different solutions from other answers but without success.
I have tried the answers from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers) question, tried to disable **ufw**, tried to reboot OS. I have even tried to update Docker and Ubuntu in hope it will finally work but it did not.
I suspect it may be problem with **iptables** but I do not know what to do with it.
There was a **sh** script on the server named *iptable.rules.sh* with the following content:

```
#/bin/sh
#blow away the DOCKER chain
sudo iptables -F DOCKER

#add http / https
sudo iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT -d 172.17.0.4
sudo iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT -d 172.17.0.4

#loopback for mongodb
sudo iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT -d 172.17.0.2 -i lo
```

But when I run it, it says:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

The only way I can run a container with internet connection is using *--net=host*, but I cannot because of linked containers.

So I am stumped and asking you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Docker updating, instance rebooting and the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with `{"iptables": false}` created by the previous maintainer. These things were overlapped by each other.

I have found the solution [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/954041/602609).
Or more described [in this article](https://www.mkubaczyk.com/2017/09/05/force-docker-not-bypass-ufw-rules-ubuntu-16-04/).

Comment: create a new file?

Comment: @Shqear what file? `/etc/docker/daemon.json` ? If so - no, it existed already. And I just ran: `sed -i -e 's/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"/g' /etc/default/ufw
ufw reload` and after this `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE`